# Android WebRTC and STUN issue

Tags: android, webrtc, stun, turn

I try to build Android version of IOS app based on webrtc . I use STUN server (not TURN , and IOS app use only STUN server) and android app doesn't work on different networks  (but IOS works fine) .

RTCConfiguration :

```
    rtcConfig.tcpCandidatePolicy = PeerConnection.TcpCandidatePolicy.DISABLED;
    rtcConfig.bundlePolicy = PeerConnection.BundlePolicy.MAXCOMPAT;
    rtcConfig.rtcpMuxPolicy = PeerConnection.RtcpMuxPolicy.REQUIRE;
    rtcConfig.iceTransportsType = PeerConnection.IceTransportsType.ALL;
    rtcConfig.continualGatheringPolicy = PeerConnection.ContinualGatheringPolicy.GATHER_CONTINUALLY;
    rtcConfig.keyType = PeerConnection.KeyType.ECDSA;
```

PS : I tried many different STUN servers(for ex.: stun:stun.l.google.com:19302 ) but no one works.

**UPD:**

ICE **SAMPLE** of STUN (ice connection failed) :

```
 {"sdp":"candidate:1911153948 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.15.33 54469 typ host generation 0 ufrag Ucsk network-id 3 network-cost 10","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}

 {"sdp":"candidate:4037141416 1 udp 1686052607 217.112.221.86 33341 typ srflx raddr 192.168.15.33 rport 54469 generation 0 ufrag Ucsk network-id 3 network-cost 10","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
```

ICE **SAMPLE** of working TURN:

```
{"sdp":"candidate:1911153948 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.15.33 53080 typ host generation 0 ufrag u6i0 network-id 3 network-cost 10","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}

{"sdp":"candidate:4037141416 1 udp 1686052607 217.112.221.86 47737 typ srflx raddr 192.168.15.33 rport 53080 generation 0 ufrag u6i0 network-id 3 network-cost 10","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}

{"sdp":"candidate:3433799847 1 udp 41885439 66.228.45.110 56124 typ relay raddr 217.112.221.86 rport 47737 generation 0 ufrag u6i0 network-id 3 network-cost 10","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"}
```

Also in log i have something looks like on connection timeout error after 15s pinging :

```
 I/libjingle: (port.cc:1413): Jingle:Conn[0xafe1c200:audio:ymVmyEYx:1:0:local:udp:192.168.15.x:59152->p7NE+tsC:1:1686052607:stun:udp:46.133.252.x:62179|C--I|0|0|7241540810645061118|-]: Sent STUN ping, id=597771634a2b427864497448, use_candidate=0, nomination=0

 I/libjingle: (port.cc:1413): Jingle:Conn[0xafe1bd00:audio:ymVmyEYx:1:0:local:udp:192.168.15.x:59152->+xyFpztR:1:2122260223:local:udp:100.73.133.x:43879|C--I|0|0|9115038255631187454|-]: Sent STUN ping, id=345231714b49377a66633056, use_candidate=0, nomination=0
```

Comment: "Not works" can mean a hundred different things. Please be clear on what exactly is not working, provide logs if available. A little more information about the stun server you're using and the android application you created. These unclear questions will never solve your queries, help us to help you.

Comment: I added more information ,@UtsavShrestha

Comment: It's unclear why you think this is a STUN issue.

Comment: First idea was that is the NAT issue of my network , but then how IOS app works ? I don't understand where to go and what to look for @mattm

Comment: @Garret Just to make sure I understand correctly: the iOS and Android client are behind the exact same network, and the iOS client doesn't require a TURN server while the Android one does?

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter Yes , you right . Two devices in different networks , ios version works without TURN

Comment: @Garret Different networks or the same network? Because if they're behind different networks, it's entirely understandable if one needs a TURN server and the other doesn't.

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter Different networks (and looks like one of them uses symmetric NAT ) , in one network both versions work fine

Comment: I am facing same issue, could you explain me how did you fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment chain, it sounds like the Android app was behind a symmetric NAT. This is usually what makes a TURN server necessary; an endpoint behind a symmetric NAT can't communicate directly with one behind another symmetric NAT or a port-restricted NAT.

So, assuming this is what's going on, there's nothing you can do; this is one of the situations where you need a TURN server.

Comment: Symmetric NAT is common when not on wifi and using the carrier network.

Comment: @Taylor Brandstetter Does STUN server send ICEs with typ relay ? Can I determinate by ICEs  if IOS app uses TURN server ?

Comment: @Garret A STUN server only provides "srflx" candidates; "relay" candidates are TURN candidates.